# spawn error while executing sh file

Tags: node.js

I am getting the following error when I tired to execute a sh file from my nodeks script. I am not getting this error when I tried in Mac but when I tried to execute it in Linux-CentOS I'am getting this problem. Please help

Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:1011:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:802:34)

I also added engine version in my package.json file but still of no use

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I corrected the cwd file path in my Linux environmnet...

```
var deploySh = spawn('sh', [ oSHFile.fileName ], {
      cwd: process.env.HOME + '/temp',
      env:_.extend(process.env, { PATH: process.env.PATH + ':/usr/local/bin'})
    });
```